# why PropTypes is not working in these component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

this is my first time with `PropTypes` and according to some articles and chatGPT, this should work but isn't working in my case. Both `activeDot` in `Dot` component and `text` in `CarouselItem` component are of any type implicitly.

Please tell me what's wrong in this.

Thanks.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { useState } from 'react'

interface ItemTextTypes {
  feature: string;
  description: string;
}

const carouselText: ItemTextTypes[] = [
  {
    feature: '100% uptime ',
    description: 'Zero Infrastructure Management',
  },
  {
    feature: 'Effortless Scalability ',
    description: 'Seamlessly handle high traffic loads',
  },
  {
    feature: 'Uninterrupted Performance ⚡️',
    description: 'Deliver exceptional user experiences, always',
  },
];

const Carousel = () => {
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div className="carousel absolute top-[45%] left-5">
      <div className="carousel-items ">
        {carouselText.map((text, i) => <CarouselItem text={text} key={i} />)}
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-dots relative top-5 flex gap-2">
        {carouselText.map((_, i) => {
            const activeDot = activeItem === i ? 'active-dot' : ''
            return <Dot activeDot={activeDot}/>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;

const Dot = ({activeDot}) => {
    return (
      <div className={`dot w-1 h-1 bg-grayish transition-5 rounded ${activeDot}}`}></div>
    );
}
Dot.propTypes = {
    activeDot: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

const CarouselItem = ({text}) => {
  return (
    <div className="carousel-item-1 flex flex-col">
      <span className="feature text-[38px] font-semibold ">{text.feature}</span>
      <span className="description text-[20px] text-grayish ">
        {text.description}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

CarouselItem.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.shape({
        feature: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        description: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired
}
```

Comment: If you're using TypeScript, you really don't need to use PropTypes. They do similar things, but TypeScript will be much more robust. The error is coming from TypeScript, which doesn't parse out the PropTypes, so as far as TS is concerned, those two components are untyped

Comment: @BrianThompson Yes, I'm using TS, then how do I define types? With `React.FC<myPropsType>` ?

Comment: Yes. where `MyPropsType` is an interface like you have with `ItemTextTypes`.

Comment: But I heard that `React.FC` is not being used anymore.

Comment: Where did you hear that? I have not heard that and a quick google search isn't turning up anything like that

Comment: https://youtu.be/xTVQZ46wc28 at 7:50 In this video, he says that it's not advised to use this after react 18 and you would find this in legacy code.

Comment: The API changed from 17-18 for `React.FC`, but that does not mean it shouldn't be used. The author of that video is jumping to an extreme that I disagree with. If you don't need children in your component `React.FC` is actually *better* in v18 than v17. If you do need children you can use `React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<YourProps>>`

Comment: Thanks, man. One more thing please, how do you define type of dom element? Do you not define any type and do the error handling while using it or while accessing define type like `element as elementType`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You shouldn't need to type DOM elements

Comment: For example - `const image = document.querySelector('img')` accessing dom elements without defining type then typescript throws error like image can be null when using in an expression. In this case, should we handle error for null possibility everytime we using it?

Comment: you shouldint be using plain javascript in react to get images etc. use a ref if you need it.

Comment: @Lith yes, I do that but what if we need a nodelist containing all img elements inside a container element